# How to switch from a desktop app view to a webview using Sikuli

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, sikuli, sikuli-x

When I click on a button from desktop application, its opening chrome browser. how can I switch to desktop to webview and back to desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need anything special. Just click the button as you normally do it.

The power of Sikuli is that it is not affected by underlying technology. It sees the screen and this is all.

So answer is:

```
click(ButtonInDesktopApp)
click(ButtonInBrowser)
```